# What is -J n Option for in GCC?

Tags: gcc

I have a final exam next week, and in the exercise paper which is given us to study, there is a gcc option that I could not find on gcc manual page.

It is something like that `gcc -J 4 program.c -o filename`.

Is there someone knows that what it is for?

Comment: Sorry but it's borderline stupid to ask you to use an undocumented option if it's not covered in your course manual.

Comment: gcc will complain with a lower case j : `-j 4` : unrecognized command line option ‘-j’ . gcc: error: 4: No such file or directory. ... But is OK with `-J 4` , i.e. an upper case J. -

Comment: @JuliePelletier I bet is an old gcc version

Comment: I tried skimming the sources at github https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/opts-global.c and the online documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/. Nowhere is documented. Gfortran has a -J defined https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Directory-Options.html

Comment: Your instructor as asking you to **memorize** compiler command-line options?  That's what documentation is for.  Requiring you to memorize command-line options isn't borderline stupid.  It's useless - you'll get them wrong anyway, and they change over time.  It's completely stupid - full stop.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, certain basic options *should* be memorized, but they would be best committed to memory by frequency of use, not by dedicated efforts to memorize.  And certainly the student should know what options there *are* even if he doesn't remember the exact flags for them.

Comment: @Wildcard The common ones will likely be memorized - i.e., `-c`, `-o`.  You are going to look up the others almost every time anyway, unless you use them enough to remember them.  Then they'll change.  It's still **stupid** to require a **student** to memorize them, and then base the student's grade on that.  It's like having a student auto mechanic memorize where a specific part is on the shelf at the one local AutoZone auto parts store.  "In what aisle and on what shelf is the left-hand muffler valve in the 4th Ave Auto Zone?"

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I agree with the proclaimed stupidity of grading students based upon memorization—full stop.  I disagree with your analogy.  To *use* a tool you should *learn* the tool.  The fact that later tools will obsolete aspects of the tool you have is irrelevant.  That's more like saying that an auto mechanic doesn't need to learn what a carburetor looks like because cars of the future (electric) won't have carburetors.  Carburetors will change.  So what?  Who will fix them in the mean time?

Comment: All is right , but I still need to learn it, somehow :)

Comment: Since you wrote `-J 4`, as in with a number, and, since it doesn't seem to match anything in gcc, I wonder if this is confused with the `-j <N>`option of `make`. In make, it sets the maximum number of compilations to run in parallel: on a four-processor system one might run `make -j4` to utilize all processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only a Gfortran specific option called `-J`, but this doesn't make sense combined with a number. Other alternative is that is being confused with make `-j n` flag that determines the maximum number of concurrent compilation process.

Comment: Hi, what's the default if -j isn't specified?  Thanks!